# Mysql Python eof then return after fetch more data

Tags: python, mysql

How can I show more data after select finish (eof) but insert more data:

```
import MySQLdb
import MySQLdb.cursors
cnx = MySQLdb.connect(user="user", 
             passwd="password",
             db="mydb",
             cursorclass = MySQLdb.cursors.SSCursor
            )
cursor = cnx.cursor()
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM individual_data")
while FOREVER:
    row = cursor.fetchone()
    if row is not None:
        print row
```

Answer (score 0):

Just:

```
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM individual_data where " +
             "datetimestamp >= TIMESTAMP '" + str(TOP_DT1) + "' and datetimestamp < TIMESTAMP '" + str(TOP_DT11) + "' order by datetimestamp, segment_id, user_id, id")
```

execute again the query to fetch more data. Like this;

```
    row1 = fetch_one(cur1)
    while row1 is not None:
        b = read_individual_data(row1)
        row = emit_individual_data(a, b)
        TOP_DT1 = TOP_DT11
        row1 = fetch_one(cur1)
```